# Processing multiple files separately in single spark submit job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have following directory structure:

/data/modelA

/data/modelB

/data/modelC
..

Each of these files have data in format (id,score), I have to do following for them separately-

1) group by scores and sort the scores in descending(DF_1: score,count)

2) from DF_1 compute the cumulative frequency for each sorted group of score (DF_2: score, count, cumFreq)

3) from DF_2 select cumulative frequencies that lie between 5-10 (DF_3: score, cumFreq)

4) from DF_3 select minimum score(DF_4: score)

5) from file select all id which have score greater than score in DF_4 and save

I am able to do this by reading the directory as wholeTextFile and creating a common dataframe for all the models, then use group by on model.

**I want to do -**

```
val scores_file = sc.wholeTextFiles("/data/*/")
val scores = scores_file.map{ line => 
  //step 1
  //step 2
  //step 3 
  //step 4
  //step 5 : save as line._1
}
```

This will help dealing with each file separately, and avoid group by.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your models are discrete values and you know then you can define all the model into a list

```
val model = List("modelA", "modelB", "modelC", ... )
```

you can have the following approach:

```
model.forEach( model => {
  val scoresPerModel = sc.textFile(model);
  scoresPerModel.map { line => 
    // business logic here
  } 
})
```

If the you don't know the model prior to computing the business logic that you have to read using the Hadoop file system API and extract the models from there.

```
private val fs = {
    val conf = new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration()
    FileSystem.get(conf)
  }
fs.listFiles(new Path(hdfsPath))
```